# How to reclaim SSD space during formating

Tags: filesystems, partition, ext4, disk, ssd

I've got a "1000GB SSD"

after creating partition (aligned to 2048) I'm down to

```
sdd      8:48   0 931.5G  0 disk
└─sdd1   8:49   0 931.5G  0 part
```

which is fine, because 1GB means 1000bytes in sales.

but after I do a standard formatting:

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 -b 4096 -j /dev/sdb1
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1       916G   28K  870G   1% /ssd1t
```

I'm down to 870 actual GB, which is getting ridicilous,

so how do I maximize user space?

Comment: With SSD best to make sure you do not use all the space, so it can do its own sector use optimization. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Improving_performance#Tuning_IO_schedulers  In Linux the default is to reserve 5% of the diskspace for the superuser (this can be adjusted using tune2fs -m). The 5% was for / so user had a little room when "full". but that was when drives were a lot smaller. You still are responsible to not fill a drive. 
`sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sdb1`
also shows settings of mount count & how often it will run fsck on reboots

Comment: With respect to your question about the SSD's unformatted size, what is the make and model number of your SSH drive, please?

Comment: Crucial BX500  CT1000BX500SSD1, 1000GB is printed on it.